# How to use default comparator in own class?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers, comparator

I want to create own data container like `STL-containers`.

```
template <class priorityType = size_t, class Compare = std::less<priorityType>>
class task_queue
{
public:
    task_queue(Compare c = Compare())
    {

    }

private:
    std::priority_queue<priorityType, std::vector<priorityType>, Compare> tasks_id;
};

int main() {
    struct foo
    {
        int a;
    };

    struct foo_compare
    {
        bool operator()(const foo& lhs, const foo& rhs) const {
            return lhs.a < rhs.a;
        }
    };

    task_queue<foo, foo_compare> queue{ foo_compare() };
}
```

I want to use `comparator`, which is passed to constructor, in `tasks_id` PQ. How can I do this?

Comment: If you pass a comparison operator in the constructor, you will not get compile-time binding of comparisons, i.e. your code will be less efficient.

Comment: @ErikAlapää, but STL containers use this stuff such way.

Comment: In general, good C++ code, including STL, tries to use compile time binding whenever possible. That is one of the reasons why std::sort in C++ is faster than C quicksort. (The C++ sort uses compile-time bound comparisons, while normal C quicksort uses function pointers).

Comment: _ -1: Simple failure to read the `priority_queue` documentation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, PQ is just example, not real application.

Comment: @Denis: Then your question is illformed because it totally misrepresents what you're trying to do. The only gap in knowledge I can see in this question is "how do I use a comparator with `priority_queue`?" And now you're not even using `priority_queue`? So what's your question, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call right [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue).

```
task_queue(Compare c = Compare()) : tasks_id(c)
{

}
```

Comment: @ForEveR, what about if `my_class` needed in such comparator, but there is not such structure, as PQ? For example, `my_class` has method, which compare its parameters?

Comment: @Denis store `Compare` object in class, in c-tor construct it right, use it, when you need.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to invoke it:

```
c(valuetocompare1, valuetocompare2);
```

It's simple as that.